# Алгоритм оптимального обхода графа с условием

Tags: java, алгоритм, графы, теория

Есть граф без отрицательных весов. Нужно из одной вершины в другую найти оптимальный путь и чтобы в цепи обязательно присутствовала вершина по условию. То есть оптимальный путь обязательно проходящий через определенную вершину.
Код не нужен просто подскажите какими алгоритмами можно попробовать реализовать.
Я только придумал, что от начальной точки до вершины по условию алгоритм Дейкстры с вычитанием ребер из графа, но только чтобы он оставался связным, а потом от вершины до конечной точки также Дейкстрой. Получившиеся ребра и будут искомым путем. Могу ошибаться не душите

Comment: Для некоторых графов не обойтись без пересечения пути. Так что, если нет прямого указания, что должно быть гарантировано отсутствие пересечения, то считайте кратчайший путь из A в С, и из С в B, и объединяйте, чтобы получить A-C-B

Comment: Из начальной вершины постройте пути во все вершины по условию. Из конечной вершины постройте пути во все вершины по условию. В каждой вершине по условию стала известна сумма длин путей. Выберите минимум.